# Is it possible to control how a boolean value will be converted to string in Github Actions?

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions, conan

Given a build matrix, containing a boolean dimension:

```
strategy:
  matrix:
    os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest]
    development_build: [True, False]
```

The `development_build` is used as a command line argument in a `run` step:

```
- run: >
    conan create
      -o build_devmode=${{ matrix.development_build }}
```

The above workflow fails, because `${{ matrix.development_build }}` seems to be converted to either strings `false` or `true`, where conan requires boolean options (such as `build_devmode` in our case) to be assigned either `False` or `True` (i.e. capitalized strings).

Is there a way to control the way a boolean workflow parameter is formatted to string when used in a `run` command?

Comment: Can you give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of two disjoint snippets? Converting `"True"` to a boolean is a violation of the YAML spec, so this should definitely not happen.

Comment: @flyx Good catch, I made a typo when copying from my code. Now fixed.

Comment: Well `"True"` instead of `True` is actually the solution you're looking for

Comment: `"True"` is indeed the workaround I am currently using (hence the initial copy-pasting error). Yet it is not the solution: `development_build` should be a boolean value, because it might be used to control conditions elsewhere in the workflow. It **is** semantically a bool. (The reason why the question is about ability to control the conversion from boolean to string).

Comment: Then the answer is some variation on what @GrzegorzKrukowski posted. But in my opinion, the proper way to fix it would be to make `conan` *not* require `True` because that's a horrible interface.

Comment: I agree with you that having a conservative interface, such as only accepting one specific spelling of boolean values, is not ideal. Sadly I have no control over the requirements of `conan` command line, only over the `yaml` of my workflows.

Comment: I don't know `conan` but the example in their manpage is `-o Pkg:with_qt=true` so I'd assume the spelling `True` is not hardcoded in conan but an issue with whatever defines that option. But yeah, if it is outside your control, you can't do much about it besides creating an issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to go:

```
strategy:
  matrix:
    os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest]
    development_build: [True, False]

- run: >
    conan create
      -o build_devmode=${{ matrix.development_build && 'True' || 'False' }}
```

Comment: This does not work, the workflow syntax is invalid: `Unrecognized named-value: 'True'. Located at position 29 within expression: matrix.development_build && True || False`

Comment: @AdN this might work with `'True' || 'False'` though it *should* work as-is according to the docs.

Comment: @flyx It tried with `"True" || "False"` but it also failed. Could you please provide a link to the docs you were mentionning?

Comment: @AdN I misread the docs, they [actually say](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions): `you must use single quotes (') around the string […] Wrapping with double quotes (") will throw an error.`

Comment: @flyx Thank you for the link. It does work with single quotes indeed. I will edit this answer to reflect that.